# Does Memcached in my server is efficient enough?

Tags: memcached

I have installed Memcached along with OPCache Zend. And I wonder why it is using so low memory. Does this stat's are good ?.

I have configured about 20sites to use it. Wordpress, Magento, Joomla
My Server spec are :
Intel Xeon X3440 Quad-Core
Memory 16GB
x2 1500 GB SATA II-HDD 7.200 rpm
CentOS 5 - Plesk 10 - RAID 1

This is output from Memcached Admin window:

[image]

This is my configuration from memcache.ini

```
extension=memcache.so
session.save_handler=memcache
session.save_path="tcp://localhost:11211?persistent=1&weight=1&timeout=1&retry_interval=15"
```

This is my configuration from memcached in sysconfig:

```
PORT="11211"
USER="memcached"
MAXCONN="512"
CACHESIZE="32"
OPTIONS="-f 1.5 -I 2800 -l 127.0.0.1"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is using a very low amount of memory because you're `CACHESIZE` variable in `/etc/sysconfig/memcached` is `32`, it will never use more than `32mb`. Try increasing it to `64` and you're server might perform slightly faster (depending on your coding implementation of course).